# CSS for touch/no touch with small devices being marked as no-touch too

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm using modernizer to add touch/no-touch to my pages and I currently have the following css:

```
.touch .desktop_only {
       display: none !important;
}
.no-touch .mobile_only {
       display: none !important;
}
```

I used to use:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px){
    .desktop_only {
       display: none !important;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1025px){
    .mobile_only {
       display: none !important;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to sort of merge them so devices that are 1024px and smaller are also classed as touch devices, instead of no-touch devices...

At the same time, I'm also running into an issue where it temporarily loads both the desktop/mobile content at the same time for a split second.

Any idea how to do this, I'm sure it will be simple but I can't work it out at all.

I tried the code below, but that just makes lots of the css go weird because of the "intial"

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px){
    .desktop_only {
       display: none !important;
    }
    .touch .desktop_only {
           display: none !important;
    }
    .no-touch .mobile_only {
           display: initial !important;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1025px){
    .mobile_only {
       display: none !important;
    }
    .touch .desktop_only {
           display: initial !important;
    }
    .no-touch .mobile_only {
           display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javaScript/jQuery to detect the touch devices and add or remove class accordingly.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    function is_touch_device() { 
        try {  
            document.createEvent("TouchEvent");  
            return true;  
        } catch (e) {  
            return false;  
        }  
    }

    if ((is_touch_device()) || ua.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad)/) 
    || ua.match(/BlackBerry/) || ua.match(/Android/)) {
        $('html').addClass('touch');
    } else {
         $('html').addClass('no-touch');
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm already doing that via moderinzer, my question is about making the css work correctly without a split second of showing both bits of content and being able to add small devices as no-touch too.